# dotnet build cmd with zip package creates a zip of lengthy subfolders for .netcoreapp 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

This is my dotnet build command for my .netcoreapp 2.1 MVC website which has two class library projects(`VinXP.Core.csproj, VinXP.Infrastructure.csproj`) referenced to the main web project(`VinXP.web.csproj`).

```
dotnet build VinXP.sln /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="E:\Publish\DRS\package" /p:OutDir="E:\Publish\DRS\out" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="E:\Publish\DRS\package\package.zip"
```

This above command doesn't create a zip in `E:\Publish\DRS\package` as mentioned in DesktopBuildPackageLocation. Instead, it creates `E:\Publish\DRS\package\VinXP.VinXPWeb.zip.`

Upon unzipping this zipped file, my build is available in a very deep sub folder as

```
E:\Publish\DRS\package\VinXP.Web.zip\Content\E_C\Working\Projects\Git\VinXPDevelopment\src\VinXP.Web\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\Out\[build]
```

Why cant it doesn't create a zip file with a build without creating a lengthy subfolder as I mentioned in `DesktopBuildPackageLocation="E:\Publish\DRS\package\package.zip"` on dotnet build command?

Attempts:

1 : Changed the path mentioned in the keys of my dotnet build command `"PackageLocation","OutDir","DesktopBuildPackageLocation"` but it only changes the root folder.

2 : Looked for .net documentation on Microsoft [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)  couldn't find it useful with my challenge faced.

Answer (score 0):

This basically depends on the CLI version you are using

If 2.X Instead of `donet build` since you are on a Windows PC you can replace this with `donet publish`

I.E 
`dotnet publish VinXP.sln /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release` `/p:PackageLocation="E:\Publish\DRS\package" /p:OutDir="E:\Publish\DRS\out"` `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true` `/maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release"` `/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="E:\Publish\DRS\package\package.zip"`

Ideally to stop the creation of recursive directories you need include(Update) the following on the package.json file

```
"publishOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "bin/**",
      "obj/**",
      "node_modules",
      "**.user",
      "**.vspscc"
    ],
```

OR

1.X Instead of `donet build` since you are on a Windows PC you can replace this with `msbuild`

I.E : `msbuild VinXP.sln /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="E:\Publish\DRS\package" /p:OutDir="E:\Publish\DRS\out" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="E:\Publish\DRS\package\package.zip"`

Refer this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6598) for more.

Refer to this for path related issues:

[1](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/2185) , [2](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/927)